# Installing OpenCart extensions locally

Tags: opencart

When installing OpenCart extensions, you´re generally given a bunch of folders that should be copied to the root directory and the extension files will find their way to the right subfolders. This works great in FTP software, but on a local installation (Mac OSX) using Finder, this operation makes Finder want to overwrite the folders completely, deleting the actual site and just keep the extension.

I can hold Alt when dragging the folders and it will give me the option to not overwrite, the problem is I have hidden files visible, which means there's now a .DS_STORE file in each folder and the ”Hold ALT”-approach doesn’t work in case there are ANY duplicate files in any of the folders.

I’m sure someone out there has stumbled upon the same problem, any ideas for how to solve such a simple but annoying problem? I do not wish to use FTP software for local file management.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14224

Comment: The great and the best *Mac OS X* fail! :-D Now seriously - why can't you use some other file manager? Why can't you copy the files manually (each file separately to the folder it belongs)?

Comment: i think its because, generally more than 20 files in a plugin, trough several long paths, like: /catalog/view/theme/default/template/controler/file.tpl (each file in a different path)

Comment: I can of course do this manually, but with the result that an operation that should take a few seconds ends up taking several minutes. Not a big deal to do it once, but it adds up and knowing myself, I´ll start to get really frustrated around the fifth time or so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem, and i found 3 different ways to solve this:

**a -** use another file manager, i personally use "Transmit" to do this sort of things;

**b -** use terminal, like: `ditto <source> <destination>`. Or easier way just type ditto, and drag the source folder, then drag the destination folder, all inside source will merge inside destination;

**c -** unzip the plugin, inside the OC folder using the terminal, like: `tar -zxvf plugin.zip`;